# Formatting API Json response using PHP to nicely display it on my website

Tags: php, json, api, curl, php-curl

So I'm new to using APIs and I just got this result after searching up a recipe that contains the word "Burger" in it. Now, how would I go about displaying this nicely in my browser?

This is the result:

'''`{"results":[{"id":492564,"title":"Falafel Burgers with Feta Cucumber Sauce","readyInMinutes":50,"servings":6,"sourceUrl":"https://www.cinnamonspiceandeverythingnice.com/falafel-burgers-with-feta-tzatziki-sauce/","openLicense":0,"image":"falafel-burgers-with-feta-tzatziki-sauce-492564.jpg"},{"id":246916,"title":"Bison Burger","readyInMinutes":45,"servings":6,"sourceUrl":"https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/buffalo_burger/","openLicense":0,"image":"Buffalo-Burger-246916.jpg"},{"id":245166,"title":"Hawaiian Pork Burger","readyInMinutes":40,"servings":4,"sourceUrl":"https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/hawaiian_pork_burger/","openLicense":0,"image":"Hawaiian-Pork-Burger-245166.jpg"},{"id":246009,"title":"Blue Cheese Burgers","readyInMinutes":55,"servings":4,"sourceUrl":"https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/blue_cheese_burgers/","openLicense":0,"image":"Blue-Cheese-Burgers-246009.jpg"},{"id":219957,"title":"Carrot & sesame burgers","readyInMinutes":50,"servings":6,"sourceUrl":"https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/11011/carrot-and-sesame-burgers","openLicense":0,"image":"Carrot---sesame-burgers-219957.jpg"},{"id":607109,"title":"Turkey Zucchini Burger with Garlic Mayo","readyInMinutes":45,"servings":6,"sourceUrl":"https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/turkey_zucchini_burger_with_garlic_mayo/","openLicense":0,"image":"Turkey-Zucchini-Burger-with-Garlic-Mayo-607109.jpg"},{"id":864633,"title":"Banh Mi Burgers with Spicy Sriracha Mayo","readyInMinutes":35,"servings":4,"sourceUrl":"http://littlespicejar.com/banh-mi-burgers-with-spicy-sriracha-mayo/","openLicense":0,"image":"banh-mi-burgers-with-spicy-sriracha-mayo-864633.jpg"},{"id":219871,"title":"Halloumi aubergine burgers with harissa relish","readyInMinutes":20,"servings":4,"sourceUrl":"https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/2196638/halloumi-aubergine-burgers-with-harissa-relish","openLicense":0,"image":"Halloumi-aubergine-burgers-with-harissa-relish-219871.jpg"},{"id":246177,"title":"Grilled Beef and Mushroom Burger","readyInMinutes":30,"servings":3,"sourceUrl":"https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/grilled_beef_and_mushroom_burger/","openLicense":0,"image":"Grilled-Beef-and-Mushroom-Burger-246177.jpg"},{"id":245343,"title":"Herbed Turkey Burger","readyInMinutes":30,"servings":8,"sourceUrl":"https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/herbed_turkey_burger/","openLicense":0,"image":"Herbed-Turkey-Burger-245343.jpg"}],"baseUri":"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/","offset":0,"number":10,"totalResults":180,"processingTimeMs":241,"expires":1620276324802,"isStale":false}`
'''

Below is the code that currently works and gives me the results up there^:

'''

```
$curl = curl_init();
$recipe= $_POST['recipe'];


curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/search?query=.$recipe",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "x-rapidapi-host: spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key: KEY_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY_PURPOSES"
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

'''

Comment: What's the expected behaviour? What do you call "nicely display"? What the server had returned to you is a JSON-encoded string. You can use `$recipes = json_decode($response, true);` and then display whatever you want, for example: `foreach ($recipes as $recipe) { echo $recipe['title']; }`

Comment: @MichałHaracewiat so I added those lines and now the error I'm getting is: 

Undefined index: title in... ------------------
Illegal string offset 'title' in...----------------
Trying to access array offset on value of type int in ------------

Comment: Did you try to figure out what could be wrong? Use this `foreach($recipes['results'] as $recipe) { echo $recipe['title']; }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wants to show formatted output in browser, you can wrap your response in "pre" tag.

```
echo "<pre>".$response."</pre>";
```